# Getting the number of entries on a TableSection

Tags: c#, ios, c#-4.0, xamarin.forms, uitableview

If I get this int 
I can set the correct height of my table...

So I try it:

```
public class Test : ContentPage{

    {...}

    tableTest = new TableView {
                        Intent = TableIntent.Data,
                        BackgroundColor = Colors.WhiteTranslucent,
                        RowHeight = 40,
                        Root = new TableRoot {
                            new TableSection () {
                                new TextCell { Text = "Contato 1",  TextColor = Color.Black, },
                                new TextCell { Text = "Contato 2", TextColor = Color.Black,  },
                            },
                        },
                    };


    layout.Children.Add (tableTest,
                        xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => 0),
                        yConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => 150),
                        widthConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => parent.Width),
                        **heightConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => **(*GetEntryCell (0,0).* * contacts.RowHeight))**
                    );

    {...}

TableSection GetEntryCell (int row, int column)
{
return (TableSection)contacts.Root [row] [column];
}


 }
```

But I don't have the number...

In the future I will get it cause I will to BD.
for while I need a solution...

this, I use to access the table:

```
TableSection GetEntryCell (int row, int column);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question but `tableTest.Root.Count` will give you the number of sections in your TableView and `tableTest.Root[0].Count` will give you the number of items in section.